# ¿Cómo poder usar 2 DatePickerDialog en un Acticity, en Xamarin Android?

Tags: datepicker, xamarin.android

Tengo un Acivity donde necesito utilizar dos DatePickerDialog, pare establecer un rango entre fechas, éste es el código que utilizo para poder crear el primer datepicker y obtener sus datos y obtener el rango inicial de la fecha requerida

```
 private void BtnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowDialog(DATE_DIALOG);
        }

        protected override Dialog OnCreateDialog(int id)
        {
            switch (id)
            {
                case DATE_DIALOG:
                    {
                        return new DatePickerDialog(this, this, year, month, day);
                    }
                    break;

                case DATE_DIALOG2:
                    {
                        return new DatePickerDialog(this, this, anio, mes, dia);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void OnDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            this.year = year;
            this.month = month;
            this.day = dayOfMonth;
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Seleccionaste :" + (month + 1) + "/" + day + "/" + year, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            string Del = (year + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + day).ToString();
            btnDel.Text = Del;
        }
```

El problema que tengo, es que quiero poder tener dos métodos OnDatSet() y dos OnCreateDialog, porque tengo que usar un segundo datepickerdialog para establecer el rango final de la fecha. Pero esos métodos son creados por Xamarin Android, así que no puedo utilizarlos dos veces, y solamente sirven para 1 datepickerdialog, alguna solución?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que cada botón "Del" "Al" tenga una fecha diferente. un método OnDataSet, para cada datepickerdialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DatePickerDialog tiene una sobrecarga que acepta un delegado que se ejecuta cuando se selecciona la fecha.

Asi que reemplaza:

```
return new DatePickerDialog(this, this, anio, mes, dia);
```

Por:

```
   return new DatePickerDialog(this, (sender, evnt) => { 
      // este metodo se ejecuta cuando se seleccione la fecha
      DateTime fechaSeleccionada = evnt.Date

   }, anio, mes, dia);
```

Y asi podras manejar cada seleccion de fecha independiente.

Por lo que tu codigo quedaria asi:

```
//..
case DATE_DIALOG:
{
    return new DatePickerDialog(this, (sender, evnt)=> {  
        // codigo para cuando se seleccione la fecha

    }, year, month, day);
}
break;

case DATE_DIALOG2:
{
    return new DatePickerDialog(this, (sender, evnt)=> {    
        // codigo para cuando se seleccione la fecha

    }, anio, mes, dia);
}
```

El parametro evnt es de tipo [`DateSetEventArgs`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.DatePickerDialog+DateSetEventArgs/), puedes ver las propiedades publica en la documentacion.

Comment: Gracias @Einer, Solucionado, pude tratar los dos datepickerdialog por separado ;)

Comment: Otra solución que encontré, fue declarar una variable tipo int,e igualarla a Date_Dialog, si ésta tomaba el valor de 1, funcionaba con datepickerdialog1, y si tomaba valor 2 funcionaba el datepickerdialog2